# AppSync Relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Lets say i have a the following requirement, A Project can have only two employees at a time 
and a employee can only be connected to One Project at a time. Whats the Best Possible Schema 
model using AWS AppSync graphql that could possible achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

never mind Figured it out!!! using  type Employee and type project.